# custom date formatting in crystal report

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, format

I am working on crysstal report and I need to format the date in the following format.

- - Format= D16C30HO in above format fields are
  - D=prefix Hard code value
  - 16=year value of systems date
  - C=Month value of systems date like A=1. January, B=2. February, C=3. March ....
  - 30=day value of system's Date
  - HO=hard code value.
  - I am a beginner for crystal report. is there any option to format    that crystal report provide us for such purposes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local datevar A := currentdate;
"D" &
totext(A,"yy") &
chr(65+asc(totext(A,"M"))-49) &
totext(A,"0M") &
"HO"
```